# How to call from supper-class method in subclass?

Tags: java, android, methods, fragment

How from class **BasicActivity** call method **stackAFragment** from subclass **Sub**?

I want to have an opportunity to replace **Fragment** in my Activity **Sub** from any Activity that extends BasicActivity by using **menu**. I am going to create a method in **Sub** for each item menu. Here is a simple example how I see it:

```
public class BasicActivity extends FragmentActivity {   
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.m_main, menu);
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
      case R.id.stad:
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) getParent().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(4); //here is me Sub.class
        //How to call method stackAFragment here?
      break;
      default:
         return false;      
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Subclass**:

```
    public class Sub extends BasicActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sub);        
    }

    public void stackAFragment() {
        Fragment f = new StadFr();      
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.the_frag, f);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an overridable method in `BasicActivity` (with an empty implementation for instance) and override it in `Sub`.

```
public class BasicActivity extends FragmentActivity {   

    protected void onTabChanged(){ }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
          case R.id.stad:
            TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) getParent().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(4); //here is me Sub.class
            onTabChanged();
      break;
      default:
         return false;      
    }
    return true;
}

public class Sub extends BasicActivity {

    protected void onTabChanged() { stackAFragment(); }

   ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `BasicActivity` class implement method `stackAFragment()` and override it in your subclass. You can also declare the method abstract in your `BasicActivity` which will then become also an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

`super.stackAFragment()`. But this method must be defined in your `BasicActivity`. It may be abstract if you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should provide you with the wanted functionality:

```
Activity activity = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity( tabHost().getCurrentTabTag() );     
if( activity instanceof Sub )
  ((Sub) activity).stackAFragment();
```